# How to remove title bar in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android-titlebar

1. Remove title bar in Android 4.2.2

   ```
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name=".RARegisterActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_raregister" >
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: Already `> 500` such a questions available in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Android xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```